# Laravel Relational Table if record exist

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to select only the products that have a record in the relational table in the selectbox.

For example I just want to get product name which is `product_id` in the `monthly_records` table

```
Tables;

Products(ID, product_name)

Suppliers(ID, supplier_name)

monthly_records(ID,pruduct_id,supplier_id,date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method is what you are looking for. With that you can do something like:

```php
Product::has('monthlyRecords')->pluck('name');
```

Comment: Can you help me? How do I write the index function? I only want to get the name of the record with product_id in the monthly_records table

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "the index function". But the query I showed should do what you described. BTW `monthlyRecords` here would be the relationship method in product model.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then Laravel's Eloquent Relationships should do the trick for you.

Here is the documentation that will help you on this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse